# Need understand search pool elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch document defines Search Pool:

> For count/search operations, defaults to fixed, size 3x # of available
>   processors. queue_size 1000.

So if I have a node with 8 Cores CPU then it can adapt 24 search operations at a time. This is the Fixed Value.

But I don't understand "queue_size 1000" what was it mean. How does it affect the search operations?

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html):

> The `queue_size` allows to *control the size of the queue of pending requests that have no threads to execute them*. By default, it is set to -1 which means its unbounded. When a request comes in and the queue is full, it will abort the request.

Setting it to 1000 means that you can have 1000 pending requests that'll be waiting to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

The correct [number of search/count pools](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) is `((# of available_processors * 3) / 2) + 1`, so in your case this means ((8 * 3) / 2) + 1 = 13 thread pools to handle search and count requests.

`queue_size` means that you can stack up to 1000 pending requests at any given time if there are no threads to handle them.